# How to do conditional formatting per row?

Tags: excel

How can I do conditional formatting per row? I'm currently trying to compare a large cross product of data, but can only compare the data in each row with the other data in the same row. I am trying to figure out how to apply conditional formatting (3-color scale) per row for a large selection (12 columns and a couple hundred rows). What is the easiest way to do this?

Just for an example, I might have a table that looks like:

```
r1 | 5    | 6    | 7    | 8
r2 | 10   | 11   | 12   | 13
r3 | 2000 | 3100 | 5400 | 1200
```

So, how would I do conditional formatting so that 5, 10, and 1200 would be the lowest for the respective rows and 8, 13, 5400 would be highest for their respective rows?

Comment: What's the exact condition you're trying to define? All values on a row less than 5? Values in column B<5, C<20, and D<1200?

Comment: I'm trying to use the 3-color scale formatting for each row between columns B through E (in this example).

Comment: The conditional formatting for each row must be applied independently from all the other rows. It's the same 3-color scale format, but only applies to the range for a single row. My suggestion is a quick VBA macro to apply the formatting for each of the rows. Otherwise, it's a manual process in this case.

Comment: Easiest way is just creating the CF rule (the 3-color scale formatting) for one single row, and then just copy format and paste it into each row you want to apply it. Bad thing about this is that you would be creating 1 rule for each row, so if you got 1000 rows of data, you would have 1000 cf rules..

Answer (score 0):

Here's some bonus VBA code to conditionally format each row individually.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CFEachRow()
    Dim singleRow As Range
    For Each singleRow In Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows
        FormatThisRow singleRow
    Next singleRow
End Sub

Private Sub FormatThisRow(ByRef thisRow As Range)
    With thisRow.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        With .Item(1)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
                .Color = 7039480
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
                .Color = 8711167
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
                .Color = 8109667
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have colour scales, or do you just need to highlight the max and min for each row?

If it's the former then I think VBA is probably your only option, as PeterT has popsed some code for. If it's the latter, then using VBA is overkill, and you can just use the conditional formatting UI to achieve what you want.

Assuming your data above is in cells A1:D3, then select it all and create a 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' rule of `A1=MIN($A1:$D1)` and change the format to green/red/whatever fill etc. Then create a similar rule with a formula `A1=MAX($A1:$D1)`, and format appropriately